# Jcrop error: undefined method 'sub'

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui, jcrop

Rails 4.0.10: I've been following this Jcrop tutorial: (http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images), and I've gotten as far as submitting the cropped image. But when I press the submit button, I get this error:

```
NoMethodError in ThingsController#update
undefined method `sub' for ["-auto-orient", "-resize", "\"500x500\""]:Array
```

I saw another question with the same error, which was fixed by changing `super.sub(/ -crop...` in lib/paperclip_processor/cropper to "`super.first.sub(/ -c...`, but this just returned the same exact error in my case. Has anyone else run into this issue with Jcrop?

---

**lib/paperclip_processors/cropper** (I put asterisks around the line highlighted on the error page)

```
module Paperclip
  class Cropper < Thumbnail
    def transformation_command
      if crop_command
        ***crop_command + super.sub(/ -crop \S+/, '')***
      else
        super
      end
    end

    def crop_command
      target = @attachment.instance
      if target.cropping?
        " -crop '#{target.crop_w}x#{target.crop_h}+#{target.crop_x}+#{target.crop_y}' "
      end
    end
  end
end
```

---

**views/things/crop.html.erb**

```
<% content_for(:head) do %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.Jcrop" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.Jcrop.min" %>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
ready = $(function() {
  $("#cropbox").Jcrop({
    onChange: update_crop,
    onSelect: update_crop,
    setSelect: [0, 0, 500, 500],
    aspectRatio: 1
  });
});

function update_crop(coords) {
  $("#crop_x").val(coords.x);
  $("#crop_y").val(coords.y);
  $("#crop_w").val(coords.w);
  $("#crop_h").val(coords.h);
}

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);

</script>
<% end %>

<%= image_tag @thing.avatar.url(:large), :id => "cropbox" %>

<%= form_for @thing do |f| %>
  <% for attribute in [:crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h] %>
    <%= f.text_field attribute, :id => attribute %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Crop" %></p>
<% end %>
```

---

**models/thing.rb**

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :large => "500x500", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "50x50!" }, :processors => [:cropper]
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  attr_accessor :crop_x, :crop_y, :crop_w, :crop_h
  after_update :reprocess_avatar, :if => :cropping?  

  def cropping?
    !crop_x.blank? && !crop_y.blank? && !crop_w.blank? && !crop_h.blank?
  end

  private

  def reprocess_avatar
    avatar.reprocess!
  end

end
```

Comment: Have you find any solution i am facing same issue.

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Where did the code inside of transformation_command come from? You are calling sub on an object that can't receive sub. You need to figure out what the return type of the call to super is, and then act accordingly. But calling super here like this is a bit smelly, as you have uncovered, it seems brittle to me as there is no contract enforcing that the superclass will return a specific kind of object.